# How to understand the Naturalized Advantage Function (NAF) in Deep Q Learning

Tags: q-learning

I'm trying to understand the NAF described on page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00748.pdf (the left column).  Mostly I want to understand

1. Why is L a lower-triangular matrix
2. Why do we exponentiate the diagonal terms
3. How do we guarantee that A will be positive? If L has negative terms isn't it possible for A to be negative.  In which case the maximum is no longer mu(x|theta)

Comment: Oh I think its by the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition cholesky decomposition